# How can i limit ngFor in Angular HTML?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i need to ngFor with limit 4 items, but if data < 4, i need to force to loop until 4

[Example at this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nmdj.png)

```
<img *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4]"
    src="assets/images/no-image.jpg"
    style="border-radius: 50%; height:90%;" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list; let i=index">
   <img *ngIf="i<4">{{item.text}}</img>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work since ngFor and ngIf cannot be used in the same element at once

Comment: you can add an inner element to give ngIf.

Comment: @Eweren Updated buddy :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4] ; let i = index">
   <img *ngIf="i < 4"
    src="assets/images/no-image.jpg"
    style="border-radius: 50%; height:90%;" />
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you define your array somewhere in your code, the easiest way would be to slice it there. Otherwise you can use the slice pipe so that you can do it right in your code. See https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

So for you you would just add `| slice:0:4` to the end of your ngFor

---

Edit: Sorry, I guess I should have read more carefully. I wrote a Plunker Demo for this. You can either use the pipe or the component logic solution.

[Plunker Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/Bimcfc0qKmwAzJUN)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
[src]="imageSrc ? imageSrc  : defaultImage"
```

Here `imageSrc` is the `src` of the image you wants to put and `defaultImage` is the `src` of the image if not available. 
Use this way

```
<img *ngIf="i < 4">
```